# Access Vue props from plain javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js, stripe-payments

I am implementing Stripe inside my application and the Stripe docs show just plain JS so I have been putting the Stripe API calls in the `script` tag without any of the Vue methods. Things have been working fine until now. I am passing props down from the parent component and I cannot access the props from inside of the Script.

Some of the Stripe documentation says to implement the JS after the HTML has rendered so I am using the `mounted` method for some of this. Any ideas on how to get this working?

I have tried putting the API call in a method and calling the method on a `click` event on the form, but when I do that it doesn't know what the `token` is that Stripe uses.

towards the bottom of the code you can see where I try to get the `this.plan` that is in `props`.

```
    <template>
  <form method="post" id="payment-form">
    <h4 class="h4Spacing">Billing Information</h4>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email Address"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input  type="text" class="form-control" id="name_on_card" name="name" placeholder="Name on Card"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address_line1" placeholder="Address"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" name="address_city" placeholder="City"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <b-form-input type="text" class="form-control" id="state" placeholder="State"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div id="card-element" class="form-control">
        <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
      </div>
      <div v-if="successful">
        <h3 class="title" data-tid="elements_examples.success.title">Payment successful</h3>
        <p class="message"><span data-tid="elements_examples.success.message">Thanks for trying Stripe Elements. No money was charged, but we generated a token: </span><span class="token">tok_189gMN2eZvKYlo2CwTBv9KKh</span></p>
        <a class="reset" href="#">
          <svg width="32px" height="32px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <path fill="#000000" d="M15,7.05492878 C10.5000495,7.55237307 7,11.3674463 7,16 C7,20.9705627 11.0294373,25 16,25 C20.9705627,25 25,20.9705627 25,16 C25,15.3627484 24.4834055,14.8461538 23.8461538,14.8461538 C23.2089022,14.8461538 22.6923077,15.3627484 22.6923077,16 C22.6923077,19.6960595 19.6960595,22.6923077 16,22.6923077 C12.3039405,22.6923077 9.30769231,19.6960595 9.30769231,16 C9.30769231,12.3039405 12.3039405,9.30769231 16,9.30769231 L16,12.0841673 C16,12.1800431 16.0275652,12.2738974 16.0794108,12.354546 C16.2287368,12.5868311 16.5380938,12.6540826 16.7703788,12.5047565 L22.3457501,8.92058924 L22.3457501,8.92058924 C22.4060014,8.88185624 22.4572275,8.83063012 22.4959605,8.7703788 C22.6452866,8.53809377 22.5780351,8.22873685 22.3457501,8.07941076 L22.3457501,8.07941076 L16.7703788,4.49524351 C16.6897301,4.44339794 16.5958758,4.41583275 16.5,4.41583275 C16.2238576,4.41583275 16,4.63969037 16,4.91583275 L16,7 L15,7 L15,7.05492878 Z M16,32 C7.163444,32 0,24.836556 0,16 C0,7.163444 7.163444,0 16,0 C24.836556,0 32,7.163444 32,16 C32,24.836556 24.836556,32 16,32 Z"></path>
          </svg>
        </a>
        <div class="caption">
          <span data-tid="elements_examples.caption.no_charge" class="no-charge">Your card won't be charged</span>
          <a class="source" href="https://github.com/stripe/elements-examples/#example-1">
            <svg width="16px" height="10px" viewBox="0 0 16 10" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
              <path d="M1,8 L12,8 C12.5522847,8 13,8.44771525 13,9 C13,9.55228475 12.5522847,10 12,10 L1,10 C0.44771525,10 6.76353751e-17,9.55228475 0,9 C-6.76353751e-17,8.44771525 0.44771525,8 1,8 L1,8 Z M1,4 L8,4 C8.55228475,4 9,4.44771525 9,5 C9,5.55228475 8.55228475,6 8,6 L1,6 C0.44771525,6 6.76353751e-17,5.55228475 0,5 C-6.76353751e-17,4.44771525 0.44771525,4 1,4 L1,4 Z M1,0 L15,0 C15.5522847,-1.01453063e-16 16,0.44771525 16,1 L16,1 C16,1.55228475 15.5522847,2 15,2 L1,2 C0.44771525,2 6.76353751e-17,1.55228475 0,1 L0,1 L0,1 C-6.76353751e-17,0.44771525 0.44771525,1.01453063e-16 1,0 L1,0 Z" fill="#AAB7C4"></path>
            </svg>
            <span data-tid="elements_examples.caption.view_source">View source on GitHub</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>



  <!--  <form action="/charge" method="post" id="payment-form">-->
<!--    <div class="form-row">-->
<!--      <label for="name"> Name </label>-->
<!--      <div id="name"></div>-->



<!--      <label for="card-element">-->
<!--        Credit or debit card-->
<!--      </label>-->
<!--      <div id="card-element">-->
<!--        &lt;!&ndash; A Stripe Element will be inserted here. &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--      </div>-->

<!--      &lt;!&ndash; Used to display form errors. &ndash;&gt;-->
<!--      <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>-->
<!--    </div>-->

<!--    <b-button class="space" id="payment-request-button">Submit Payment</b-button>-->
<!--  </form>-->


    <b-button class="space" type="submit" >Submit Payment</b-button>
  </form>
</template>

<script>
  import registerElements from './stripeMethods'
  // Create a Stripe client.
  let stripe = Stripe('pk_test_TYooMQauvdEDq54NiTphI7jx');

  // Create an instance of Elements.
  let elements = stripe.elements();

  // Custom styling can be passed to options when creating an Element.
  // (Note that this demo uses a wider set of styles than the guide below.)
  let style = {
    base: {
      color: '#32325d',
      fontFamily: '"Roboto", Helvetica, sans-serif',
      fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
      fontSize: '16px',

    },
    invalid: {
      color: '#fa755a',
      iconColor: '#fa755a'
    }
  };

  let card = undefined;
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';
import authService from '../../services/authService';
  export default {
    props: ['plan'],
    data: function() {
      return {
        successful: false,
        monthly: {
          id: 'prod_Flp17jVPzNUfFz',
          price: 25
        },
        annual: {
          id: 'prod_Flp17jVPzNUfFz',
          price: 215 
        }
      }
    },
    methods: {
      submitPayment: function () {

      }
    },
    mounted() {
      // Create an instance of the card Element.
      let card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

      // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
      card.mount('#card-element');

      // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
      card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        let displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        if (event.error) {
          displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
        } else {
          displayError.textContent = '';
        }
      });

      // Handle form submission.
      let form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
      form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        event.preventDefault();

        stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
          if (result.error) {
            // Inform the user if there was an error.
            let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
            errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
          } else {
            // Send the token to your server.
            stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
            return result.token
          }
        }).then(function (result) {
          console.log(result);
          axios({
            method: "POST",
            url: '/api/checkout',
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.idToken}`,
            },
            data: {
              subscription: result.id,
              plan: this.plan     <----------------------------------- not working
            },
          }).then(function (res) {
            // alert("It went through! How? ")
          }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
          });
        });
      });

      // Submit the form with the token ID.
      function stripeTokenHandler(token) {
        // Insert the token ID into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        let form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
        let hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'stripeToken');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', token.id);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem of scoping, nothing more.  When you try to access `this.plan`, `this` is a reference to the callback being executed from the event listener.  You need to declare a variable that is assigned the Vue instance to access these fields anywhere in a method:

```
mounted() {
  var vm = this;
  // Create an instance of the card Element.
  let card = elements.create('card', {style: style});

  // Add an instance of the card Element into the `card-element` <div>.
  card.mount('#card-element');

  // Handle real-time validation errors from the card Element.
  card.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
    let displayError = document.getElementById('card-errors');
    if (event.error) {
      displayError.textContent = event.error.message;
    } else {
      displayError.textContent = '';
    }
  });

  // Handle form submission.
  let form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
  form.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
    console.log(event);
    event.preventDefault();

    stripe.createToken(card).then(function (result) {
      if (result.error) {
        // Inform the user if there was an error.
        let errorElement = document.getElementById('card-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
      } else {
        // Send the token to your server.
        stripeTokenHandler(result.token);
        return result.token
      }
    }).then(function (result) {
      console.log(result);
      axios({
        method: "POST",
        url: '/api/checkout',
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${authService.idToken}`,
        },
        data: {
          subscription: result.id,
          plan: vm.plan     <----------------------------------- not working
        },
      }).then(function (res) {
        // alert("It went through! How? ")
      }).catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
      });
    });
  });
```

Comment: Oh so that is it? is that because it is inside of the function, inside of the mounted hook?

Comment: The way javascript handles scopes and inner functions and stuff hides `this` a lot of the time.  For Vue projects, I will do this a lot simply because if you ever create anonymous callbacks or other inner functions, they change the `this` variable to their own scope.